# how to run script in multiple devices in appium

Tags: testng, appium, appium-android

Script is not running parallelly on both devices, though app is opened on both devices, actions are taking place in only one device. Other device becomes idle.

Desired capabilities:

```
@Parameters({ "deviceName_", "udid_", "platformVersion_", "URL_" })
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(String deviceName_,String udid_,String platformVersion_,String URL_) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();   
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName_);
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion_);
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");  
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.*******"); //Replace with your app's package
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.******.login.SplashScreen");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid_);
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://"+URL_), capabilities);
}

Testng xml:

<suite name="Suite"  parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="deviceName_" value="ZX1D649DLB"/>  
        <parameter name="udid_" value="192.168.50.232:5151"/>   
        <parameter name="platformVersion_" value="6.0"/>
        <parameter name="URL_" value="127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bm.search_592.ParallelDevice"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
     <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="deviceName_" value="BEPN557TU8SOR4CE"/>    
        <parameter name="udid_" value="192.168.50.201:5252"/>   
        <parameter name="platformVersion_" value="6.0.1"/>
        <parameter name="URL_" value="127.0.0.1:4726/wd/hub"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bm.search_592.ParallelDevice"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the udid parameters are wrong, in order to find the correct udid for each device execute below command on Terminal or CMD:

> adb devices

The serial number is what you need in the output.

And I see you are using different ports, that's what you need but open 2 appium server in parallel with selected port and caps.

Comment: Connected device through wifi. Given udid is mobile ip with tcp port number.